# substitute for System.Net.Icertificatepolicy in WP7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I was trying to use secure web service URL in my WP7 Application but do not want to for installation  of certificates on each device. I find that there is no IcertificatePolicy Interface in WP7, which available in .Net.

In .Net i have used this many times to communicate with secure web services without installing certificates on the the client machine.
The code for .Net is available in this article [Click here](http://www.articlesnmore.in/ShowArticle-articleid-22-title-Consuming_a_secure_HTTPS_web_service_on_SSL_in_.net.htm)

But not able to find its substitute in WP7. Is this available in WP7 or 7.1?
Please suggest what can i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 has limited support for working with anything but a very small number of Root CAs and does not include (as you've discovered) an easy way to work around this.

I'd expect that the cost of a suitable SSL certificate will be much less than the time you spend trying to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**Be aware this disables certification validation!**

You can try this, data will still be encrypted.

```
public class CustomCertificationPolicy: ICertificatePolicy
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Disable validation and accept the certificate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="srvPoint"></param>
    /// <param name="certificate"></param>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <param name="certificateProblem"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Be aware this disables certification validation!**